# FOR loop optimization for comparing two dataframes in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have the below code, where I am trying to go each and every row of certain column of a dataframe and check that value into another dataframe to insert a value in column4 of first dataframe

```
for (i in 1:length(DF$Date)){
  if (DF$column1[i] %in% DF_2$column_1){
    DF$column4[i] <- "YES"
  }
}
```

The code works fine, as I have millions of records it is taking huge time to perform the task.

It would be helpful if anyone has an efficient way to tackle this in short span

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a `for` loop here since `%in%` is vectorised. A simple `ifelse` should work.

```
DF$column4 <- ifelse(DF$column1 %in% DF_2$column_1, 'YES', 'NO')
```

You could also do this in the following way :

```
DF$column4 <- c('NO', 'YES')[(DF$column1 %in% DF_2$column_1) + 1]
```

which might be faster on larger datasets.

Comment: Thank you very much @Ronak, helped me as always :)

Answer (score 3):

Let's compare 3 approaches. The first is the `for` loop in your question. A second is the one Ronak answered, using `ifelse()` which makes the operation faster. However, the operator `%in%` itself is somewhat slow, so if performance is really a concern you can get an even faster solution using indexing with names.

For example, using the `words` dataset in the package `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)

DF1 <- data.frame(column1 = sample(words, 700))
DF2 <- data.frame(column1 = sample(words, 700))
```

We can compare these methods:

```
bench::mark(for_loop={
  res1 <- character(nrow(DF1))
  for (i in seq_len(nrow(DF1))){
    if (DF1$column1[i] %in% DF2$column1){
      res1[i] <- "YES"
    }
  }
  res1
},
ifelse = {
  res2 <- ifelse(DF1$column1 %in% DF2$column1, "YES", "")
},
by_names = {
  res3 <- setNames(rep("", nrow(DF1)),
                   DF1$column1)
  res3[intersect(DF1$column1, DF2$column1)] <- "Yes"
},check = FALSE)

# A tibble: 3 x 13
#     expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
#     <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#   1 for_loop     7.94ms   8.49ms      112.     3.8MB     8.98    50     4
#   2 ifelse      200.6us  214.8us     4494.    60.7KB     4.09  2197     2
#   3 by_names     73.4us   78.2us    12342.    73.9KB    17.5   5628     8
#  ... with 5 more variables: total_time <bch:tm>, result <list>, memory <list>,
#    time <list>, gc <list>
```

As you can see, the `ifelse` method is 40x faster than the `for` loop, and indexing by name is 3x faster than with `ifelse`.

If the `ifelse` method is fast enough, you should use it as it is easier to read, but if your dataset is too big, selecting by name can add some welcome performance.

NB: the three solutions do give the same result, but the third method has names, hence the `check=FALSE` argument.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the simplified explanation @Alexlok

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the efficiency by using `fastmatch`:

```
library(fastmatch)
DF$column4 <- c("", "YES")[(DF$column1 %fin% DF_2$column1) + 1]
```

or:

```
DF$column4 <- ""
x[fmatch(DF_2$column1, DF$column1, 0)] <- "Yes"
```

Benchmark (using Data from @Alexlok):

```
library(stringr)
set.seed(42)
DF <- data.frame(column1 = sample(words, 700))
DF_2 <- data.frame(column1 = sample(words, 700))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(control=list(order="block")
 , Vin = {x <- character(nrow(DF))
   for (i in 1:nrow(DF)) {
     if (DF$column1[i] %in% DF_2$column1) {
       x[i] <- "YES"
     }
   }
   x}
 , RonakShah1 = ifelse(DF$column1 %in% DF_2$column1, 'YES', 'NO')
 , RonakShah2 = c('NO', 'YES')[(DF$column1 %in% DF_2$column1) + 1]
 , Alexlok = {x <- setNames(rep("", nrow(DF)), DF$column1)
   x[intersect(DF$column1, DF_2$column1)] <- "Yes"
   x}
 , fmatch = {x <- character(nrow(DF))
   x[fmatch(DF_2$column1, DF$column1, 0)] <- "Yes"
   x}
 , fin = c('NO', 'YES')[(DF$column1 %fin% DF_2$column1) + 1]
 )
#Unit: microseconds
#       expr       min         lq        mean     median         uq       max
#        Vin 13782.353 20549.5995 21467.31764 21795.3050 22845.0755 36143.621
# RonakShah1   281.118   308.1385   322.57051   316.5560   340.8620   362.097
# RonakShah2    60.906    66.5565    68.17693    67.8925    69.4110    88.363
#    Alexlok   162.817   179.6205   184.22998   182.3755   187.8450   257.323
#     fmatch    27.949    29.0590    29.90183    29.5275    30.0465    49.612
#        fin    30.446    31.0340    31.86467    31.5135    31.9540    49.817
```